# Is it possible to add DLL library from Excel for Windows to Excel for OS X? (specifically "VBScript Regular Expressions")

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

I frequently use the `VBScript Regular Expressions` library in Excel Workbooks I create on Office for Windows. But sometimes I need to open those workbooks on Excel for Mac, and (obviously) that reference is not available.

Is it possible to "import the functionallity" of such DLL from a Windows machine to a Mac? (directly copying the file doesn't work)

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: yes. You run the Windows version of Excel in a VM on OSX or run Wine ... see [5 Ways to Run Windows Software on a Mac](http://www.howtogeek.com/187359/5-ways-to-run-windows-software-on-a-mac/)

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok. I'll have to figure out how to deal without that library... It's a shame it's not available on Excel for Mac

Comment: See also this [su] question [How to develop an Excel Macro that contains regular expressions so it will work in Windows and Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13995007)